# Create a comparison in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, comparison

I working on an app to show some information about cities

In an array I have two parameters
1- languages (I don't know how many there are) 
2- the number of people that speak on that language

I get this data from an server

here is this two paramter in JSon

```
"language": "French",
"number": "12321",
```

these data among other data is saved in an array

I Just want to get the most used language with the pecentage
for example French with 35%
how can I do it in swift?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include relevant code. Show where you need help and clearly explain what issues you are having with the code.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a code writing service. Show us what you tried, where you got stuck, and then we can help with a concrete issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation

let serverOutput = Data("""
[
    {
        "language": "French",
        "number": "12"
    },
    {
        "language": "English",
        "number": "10"
    }
]
""".utf8)

struct LangueUsers: Codable {
    let language: String
    let number: Int

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case language
        case number
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        language = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .language)
        let rawNumber = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .number)
        guard let number = Int(rawNumber) else {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Int.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys.number], debugDescription: "\(rawNumber) can't be convert to Int"))
        }
        self.number = number
    }
}

struct LangueUsersPercent: CustomStringConvertible {
    let language: String
    let share: Double

    init(language: String, number: Int, all: Int) {
        self.language = language
        self.share = Double(number) / Double(all)
    }

    var description: String {
        return String(format: "%@ - %0.1f%%", language, share * 100)
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
//1
var output = try decoder.decode([LangueUsers].self, from: serverOutput)
//2
let allUser = output.reduce(0) { (reult, languageUsers) -> Int in
    reult + Int(languageUsers.number)
}
//3
output.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    lhs.number > rhs.number
}
//4
let response = output.map {
    LangueUsersPercent(language: $0.language, number: $0.number, all: allUser)
}
print(response[0])
```

The code assumes that the output from a server is in `serverOutput` variable. So steps need to achieve your task:

1. decode your JSON to swift structure (called `LangueUsers`) using swift codable. Keep in mind that by default it won't convert string values to int, so I have to create a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` initializer
2. count the sum of all users (you can do it using for loop or reduce like in my example)
3. sort your list, so the language with the most users will be first
4. this step is optional, but I've added a separate structure that will help us generate output and in this step, we are rewriting our input structures to output ones

Hope this is clear for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have already got the data from a server and I have an array of the result, I just need to know how I can filter these result

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
// Example JSON
const exampleJSON = {
  "people": [
{
"language": "French",
"number": 12321,
},
{
"language": "English",
"number": 7000,
}
]
};

// Parse it
const parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(exampleJSON));
const speakers = [...parsed.people];

// Count number of all speakers and let it be as 100%
let sumAllSpeakers = 0;
parsed.people.reduce((previous, current) => {
  sumAllSpeakers = previous.number + current.number;
  return previous;
});

// Compare fucntion
const compareSpeakers = (speaker1, speaker2) => {

  if (speaker1.number > speaker2.number) {
    return -1;
  }

   if (speaker1.number < speaker2.number) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

// Create new array with statistic sorted from max number
const statisticsOfSpeakersInPersent = speakers
.sort((speaker1, speaker2) => compareSpeakers(speaker1, speaker2))
.map(speaker => {
  return {...speaker, ...{inPersent: speaker.number * 100 / sumAllSpeakers + '%'}}
});
```

I hope this example helps you.

Out:

> [ { language: 'French',
>       number: 12321,
>       inPersent: '63.76999120128358%' },   { language: 'English',
>       number: 7000,
>       inPersent: '36.23000879871642%' } ]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help